# PowerShell script for Wake On Lan Status

Tags: powershell

I have some questions about a PowerShell script I need to write:

1. My script gets a list of servers' IP and it's output has to be the status of each server's WakeOnLan parameter.
   The output also has to include the time it took my function to return all the statuses of all the servers.
   Measure-Command does not work in this case, because my function is pretty long and it gets a list of hundreds IPs.

Does anyone know how to make my function write the following output:

```
"The total time of providing WakeOnLan status for ___(number) servers is ___(minutes).
```

2. After writing my function in some cases it can not run the Connect-HPEBIOS
   command (when the output is more than one IP): It prints that it can not connect because of credentials (even though they are being written in my function correctly), but after trying to call my function with (only that specific IP - and not a list of IPs) the function works properly without printing an error about the credentials.

Does anyone have an idea what should I do in the cases where my output is more than one IP? How can I fix it?

3. One more question- Do I have to refer in my function to the different possibilities of different ILO versions? Can there be problems performing the Connect-HPEBIOS command in the different versions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It'd be helpful to able to see the code in question.

Comment: Please read [ask]. And put multiple questions into ... multiple questions. Otherwise the question is likely to be put on hold for being too broad. For 1st store a datetime stamp into a variable `$StartDT = [datetime]::Now` and for the end and simply subtract them using the `.TotalMinutes` property of the resulting TimeSpan-Object with the [-f format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html). 2nd iterate over multiple input or use index[0] of the input. 3rd no idea.